# Markov Chain, Initial distribution.

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

On a square board with 40 spaces (such as in the game of Monopoly), we move a pawn by throwing 2 fair dice. At each step, we cast the 2 dice and add up their face values, and then move the pawn counter-clockwise on the board by as many positions.
I want to construct a Markov Chain by defining State Space S = {1,2,...,40}.
and let yᵢ be the sum of the 2 coin tosses at the ith cast.
Then y1, y2,... is a sequence of iid random variables with probabilities as follows
P(y1 = k) = 0 when k=1; 1/36 when k=2 or 4; 2/36 when k=3 or 11, 3/36 when k=4 or 10; 4/36 when k=5 or 9; 5/36 when k=6 or 8; 6/36 when k=7.
I also define initial state as X₀ = 1; X1 = y1; X2 = X1 + y2,..., X(n+1)= Xn + yn;
What is the initial distribution? Is it the 1X12 row vector (0, 1/36, 2/36,..., 1/36)? but I have already fixed the initial state as 1? so is it the row vector (1,0,...,0)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The "initial distribution" is literally just the distribution at the start, of the initial value. You've defined $X_0$ to be $1$. So your initial distribution is just the point mass at $1$, often denoted $\delta_1$.

It oesn't matter how you generate the Markov chain. The law of your step is irrelevant. All that matters is how you start. It's $\delta_1$.

You could have, if you wanted, let $X_0$ be uniform on $S = \{1, ..., 40\}$. In this case, your initial distribution would be $\operatorname{Unif}(\{1, ..., 40\})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That helps!

Comment: @LLTAN Happy to help! Remember to hit the tick (/checkmark) to accept if it solves your question. That way, others know that you are happy!